# WKWebView CALayer - iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have seen a lot bugs being reported around `WKWebView` on **iOS 13**
I was adding rounded corners to `WKWebView` and `UIWebView` disappeared on iOS 13 but works fine in **iOS 12**.

**This is how I set the rounded corners on the WKWebView**

```
 public override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    webView.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 10)
}

extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

If I comment out `layer.mask = mask`, the `WKWebView` doesn't disappear but also doesn't have rounded corners anymore. **Is there a workaround for this?**

Comment: just tried and it works for me... the webview does not disappear is there maybe something else going on?

Comment: I tried calling it from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` over `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and that worked

Comment: well maybe the bounds were wrong on viewWillLayoutSubviews you could just log what you get for the bounds in that method

Comment: By the way since iOS 11 you have the maskedCorners property on CALayer to deal with this